# Adding a project did not add dll file

Tags: c#, dll

I am trying to add a project to the main - which has four projects- as instructed in Step by Step (Microsoft Visual C# 2013 book_Chapter 20 "Delegate") after adding reference to other project and add using  as well I got a message "dll - of the referenced project- could not be found" and I couldn't find a dll file for the added project

Comment: Did you add this project to your solution?

Comment: Which version  of Microsoft Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: Check if there are build errors in the new project